# Ubuntu Pygame random "Crashing"

Tags: python, ubuntu, crash, pygame

I'm making a game in Python and PyGame, it's a scrolling 2d Shoot-em-up style game, and I'm having an annoying problem. For some reason, while I'm playing it, randomly it will crash, but instead of closing the window, the music and sound effects cut out, and I can still play it, but when I try to close it from there it won't close.

At first I thought this was a problem in the code, but my friend who is also working on it is using Windows, and this crashing has never happened to him, while I'm running Ubuntu and it happens usually within the first 30 seconds to a minute of playing. It's very annoying and I'm worried that it's not just a problem with my computer. Is this something wrong with my python or PyGame installation? I never get an error message, but I also can only close the window by closing the terminal.

The source code can be found on github here - https://github.com/wazzup771/NLC-2015

but I'm not sure where to even look. We are turning in this project tomorrow, so anyway I can fix this would be great. Thank you.

EDIT: here is a screenshot of my system monitor, so I think I know what is going on, I just don't know why it is doing it.

[image: Screen capture of system monitor with areas of interest]

Area 1 is where a level is loaded, it seems like 1 core does all the work while the other 3 sit back, at 2 is when the music stopped. The 4th core instantly started working at 100% for no reason. and point 3 is where I tried to click the close button. The other 3 cores die down, but the core working at 100% (now the 3rd core) doesn't budge.

I have NO idea what is causing this, but it was replicated on another Linux machine.

Comment: So it doesn't crash?  There is no stack trace?

Comment: Nope. Just the music stops and I can tell that it will no longer close from the quit button. If I try to close it while the music is still playing it works perfectly.